# Block an IPv6 Address in Salesforce sites (Digital Experience)

Tags: digital-experience

Came across a use case where I need to block an IPv6 address from accessing Salesforce Digital experiences site. It is fairly simple to block an IPv4 address by skipping the specific address from the whitelist range on the guest user profile login IP ranges. Does any one know how to do a similar thing with the IPv6 address or is it even possible?

Note: I am not very good with the networking concepts of IPv6 address so please consider the question as a newbie question. I can edit the question to include more details to make the question more comprehensible.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_profiles_epui_login_ip_ranges_edit.htm&type=5

Comment: @identigral I am aware of this help article but since I do not understand the ranges very well, I am not able to add the range. Suppose I want to skip IP (2601:641:8000:7a0:7b39:5423:f746:32a7) what should my range look like? Need help in that

Comment: @identigral Please note that the above IP is a fake IP, but hope I was able to clarify my ask.

Comment: Have you checked networking-focused resources like [Server Fault StackExchange](https://serverfault.com/search?tab=newest&q=ipv6&searchOn=3)?